# Research in a Python dataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe composed of a column 'Letter' filled with letter going from A to Z and a column 'Lane' filled with 0 and 1. I would like to know if there is the letter H and if yes how many times on lane 0 and how many times on lane 1.

Basically I would like to know: 
the number of 'H' on each track (0 and 1).

In addition I would like to know how to perform a multiple search. That is to say search two letters at the same time?

Can someone please help me?

Comment: IF you do `df.groupby(['Letter', 'Lane']).count().reset_index()` you'll have a nice `df` grouped with how many coutns per lane per letter. Then, you can use this `df` to filter by letter using `loc` and retrieve info

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
df[(df['Letter'] = 'H') & (df['Lane'] == 0)].count()
df[(df['Letter'] = 'H') & (df['Lane'] == 1)].count()
```